# ¿Error en conda_python(envpath, conda = miniconda)?

Tags: r, rstudio

Hace unos días formatee mi PC, pues necesitaba mantenimiento e instale r y rstudio con las siguientes características

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tm_0.7-10          NLP_0.2-1          reshape2_1.4.4     wordcloud_2.6     
 [5] RColorBrewer_1.1-3 forcats_0.5.2      stringr_1.5.0      purrr_1.0.0       
 [9] readr_2.1.3        tidyr_1.2.1        tibble_3.1.8       ggplot2_3.4.0     
[13] tidyverse_1.3.2    dplyr_1.0.10       tidytext_0.4.0     rtweet_1.0.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.9          lubridate_1.9.0     lattice_0.20-45     prettyunits_1.1.1  
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1    utf8_1.2.2          slam_0.1-50         R6_2.5.1           
 [9] cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.8          backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2       
[13] httr_1.4.4          pillar_1.8.1        progress_1.2.2      rlang_1.0.6        
[17] curl_4.3.3          googlesheets4_1.0.1 readxl_1.4.1        rstudioapi_0.14    
[21] Matrix_1.5-1        googledrive_2.0.0   bit_4.0.5           munsell_0.5.0      
[25] broom_1.0.2         compiler_4.2.2      janeaustenr_1.0.0   modelr_0.1.10      
[29] askpass_1.1         pkgconfig_2.0.3     openssl_2.0.5       tidyselect_1.2.0   
[33] fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.3.0          dbplyr_2.2.1       
[37] withr_2.5.0         SnowballC_0.7.0     grid_4.2.2          jsonlite_1.8.4     
[41] gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3     
[45] scales_1.2.1        tokenizers_0.3.0    cli_3.5.0           stringi_1.7.8      
[49] fs_1.5.2            xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2      generics_0.1.3     
[53] vctrs_0.5.1         tools_4.2.2         bit64_4.0.5         glue_1.6.2         
[57] hms_1.1.2           parallel_4.2.2      timechange_0.1.1    colorspace_2.0-3   
[61] gargle_1.2.1        rvest_1.0.3         haven_2.5.1
```

Sin embargo cada vez que inicio un nuevo script me genera este error:

```
Error in conda_python(envpath, conda = miniconda) : no conda environment exists at path 'C:/Users/Memo/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate'Calls: do.call -> <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> conda_python Execution halted.
```

[image: Error]

Al correr código no me genera ningún error, funciona bien, pero me gustaría saber el porqué de este error y así poder corregirlo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No pude encontrar la solución, lo que hice fue desinstalar la versión 4.2.2 e instale la versión 4.1.3 y el error se soluciono, la parecer la version de R no era compatible con las rutas de miniconda que estaban en mi euipo.